# Devops pipeline builds: NuGetToolInstaller@1

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have inherited a .Net Framework 4.6 application for which I have developed an Azure Devops build pipeline which works.

Having upgraded the application to use .Net Framework 4.8 and xUnit the same build pipeline is failing.

One thing I am noticing in the output logs is that NuGetToolInstaller@1 is finding version 5.4.0.

If I look at the logs I also see `Agent.ToolsDirectory=D:\A\F4\_work\_tool` and in there I can see `NuGet\5.4.0`.

I manually copied v6.3.1.1 to that directory but DevOps is still picking up v5.4.0.

I have the inputs `checkLatest: true` or `versionSpec: 6.x` but they still appear to just find v5.4.0.

Could someone give me a steer on what is controlling this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could i confirm with you that  NuGetToolInstaller@1 still find version 5.4.0 even you set versionSpec: 6.x? I tested in my self-hosted agent(windows) and NuGetToolInstaller@1 can find the specified version in my cache folder that includes other versions(3.x,4.x,5.x,6.x). You can check my [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goHD6.png). Besides, could you share your logs and your sample yaml file with us to better understand why your build is failing?